# Force non-ssl on WordPress RSS feeds in htaccess, using cloudflare

Tags: htaccess, rss, ssl

I have a site behind cloudflare's free SSL service. However I can no longer validate my RSS feeds at `https://validator.w3.org` because i get `Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error` and thus I am unable to submit my site to Apple News Publisher.

Accessing the RSS feeds in the browser (over SSL) is fine and they update ok in Feedly and other readers.

I am aware this is a problem between the TLS versions between the sites and the problem lies with them rather than me or cloudflare.

To solve this problem I would like to serve anything at `http(s)://domain.tld/feed*`  without SSL

I've tried adding a page rule on cloudflare to switch off SSL but that doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried adding some code to my htaccess to handle this after cloudflare has finished but I end up with redirect errors.

i've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/feed
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Can anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I must confess that right now I am feeling [like this](https://xkcd.com/979/).

I think I might found a solution. I had the exact same problem and all I had to do was to add a page rule in my CloudFlare config.

Create a new page rule like this:

```
http://*.domain.com/feed/*
```

And set "SSL" to "Off", and make it the first rule.

And that's it. After cleaning cache it will be working like a charm. At least it did for me!

Comment: Oh... <3 for XKCD

Comment: This also worked for me